# Java named capture group not found in spite of match

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use Java's named capture group to extract the integer from the string. I know there are other simpler methods for just extracting the number, but I want to use regex as I want to ensure that the rest of the string matches the pattern.

```
line = "Data: 5 Total";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Data: (?<value>\\d+) Total)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
assert m.matches();
String value = m.group("value");
```

The above code fails returns,`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`

The only group being captured is the complete input string, `"Data: 5 Total"`.
Why is the inner, named group, `"value"`, not being captured?

Comment: Why are you using `assert` for that?  The whole point of assertions is that they can be enabled or disabled at run time without changing the results ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)).  They're **not** for normal control flow.  Come to think of it, how do you know it's capturing the complete input string?  If the `assert m.matches();` line doesn't get executed, `m.group()` should throw an IllegalStateException just like `m.group("value")` does.

Comment: You are right. I did not understand how `assert` worked at the time I wrote this post. I have now replaced it completely.

Comment: @Alan My understanding now is that, I should instead use if statements and throw an exception in the else block. Is this correct?

Comment: You definitely should use an `if` statement, but should you throw an exception if the match fails?  I don't know how your code is being used, so I can't tell you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `find()` to make the regex engine find its match before you try to access the match result. You can remove the capturing group around the entire pattern as well and refer to group() to get the entire match.

```
String s  = "Data: 5 Total";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Data: (?<value>\\d+) Total");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    String value = m.group("value");
    // do something with the match result ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason as to why m.matches() is not sufficient? I feel m.matches() implicitly calls find()

Comment: The `matches()` method matches the regular expression against the entire string passed to `matcher()`. If the regular expression matches the entire string, then `matches()` returns true. If not, returns false.

Comment: But if a match is found in `matches()`, then shouldn't it have also found the groups in it? What if the string is `"Data: 5 Total XQWEQWE"`? In this case, I want to be notified that there is no match for the full string? Do I need to have an additional call to `matches()` to accomplish that?

Comment: No use beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors. `^Data: (?<value>\\d+) Total$`